# OpenCV decode CV_32FC1 into png

Tags: opencv, floating-point, mat

I would like to convert a OpenCV CV_32FC1 Mat into a png to save it and later use it in a Unity Shader.
I would like to decode it so that the first channel contains the highest 8 bits, the second channel the next 8 bits and the third channel the next 8 bits.

Edit> I actually mean the highest bits of the mantissa. Otherwise discarding 8 Bit (since I need 3 channels for imwrite) would destroy the float-representation.

I already have this working the other way around with this function:

```
Mat prepareLUT(char* filename){
    Mat first;
    first = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat floatmat;
    first.convertTo(floatmat, CV_32F);
    std::vector<Mat> channels(3);
    split(floatmat, channels);
    Mat res(Size(960,1080), CV_32FC1);
    res = channels[2]/255 + channels[1]/(255.0*255.0) + channels[0]/(255.0*255.0*255.0);
    return res;
}
```

but I am unable to do this the other way around.

My first idea was the following:

```
void saveLUT(Mat in, char const* filename){
    Mat m1 = Mat(imageSize, CV_8UC1);
    Mat m2 = Mat(imageSize, CV_8UC1);
    Mat m3 = Mat(imageSize, CV_8UC1);

    m1 = (in*(0xFF*0xFF*0xFF-1));
    m2 = (in*(0xFF*0xFF-1));
    m3 = (in*(0xFF-1));

    std::vector<Mat> channels;
    channels.push_back(m1);
    channels.push_back(m2);
    channels.push_back(m3);
    Mat out;
    merge(channels, out);
    imwrite(filename, out);
}
```

I thought all the bits left and right of my 8 Bit range would be cut-off, giving me the right Mat, but it always outputs some gray image.

The second approach was to work with float mats, then convert them to Char Mats to cut-off the trailing numbers:

```
void saveLUT(Mat in, char const* filename){
    Mat m1f(imageSize, CV_32FC1);
    Mat m2f(imageSize, CV_32FC1);
    Mat m3f(imageSize, CV_32FC1);

    Mat m1, m2, m3;

    m3f = in*255;
    m3f.convertTo(m3, CV_8UC1);
    m3.convertTo(m3f, CV_32FC1);

    m2f = (in*255-m3f)*255;
    m2f.convertTo(m2, CV_8UC1);
    m2.convertTo(m2f, CV_32FC1);

    m1f = ((in*255-m3f)*255-m2f)*255;
    m1f.convertTo(m1, CV_8UC1);

    std::vector<Mat> channels;
    channels.push_back(m1);
    channels.push_back(m2);
    channels.push_back(m3);
    Mat out;
    merge(channels, out);
    imwrite(filename, out);
}
```

This way I always subtract the numbers that are too high by subtracting the result for the previous channel before multiplying, but this still gives me a gray result as the one below.
[image: Sample result]
Any Idea how to tacle this?

Comment: you know that floats are 32 bit = 4 channels each 8 bit? didnt read your whole question yet, just the first thing that came in my mind...

Comment: what is your intention in coding the channels in this way? Would it be the same to have an array of 4 chars (1 zero res your channels) and interpret them as a float?

Comment: Yes, I know that floats are 32 bit, but imwrite only saves 3-channel images and therefore I just throw away some of the precision.

To your second question: The float Mat is a map that can be used for remap. I got this map with the stereo-calibration functions. I want to write these Maps to a png file and then load them in a Unity Shader to decode them again and to use them as Maps.

Comment: you can save 4 channel (each 8 bit) png with imwrite.

Comment: Not according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite). It says>
The function imwrite saves the image to the specified file. The image format is chosen based on the filename extension (see imread() for the list of extensions). Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

Comment: my doc on http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite says " It is possible to store PNG images with an alpha channel using this function. To do this, create 8-bit (or 16-bit) 4-channel image BGRA, where the alpha channel goes last. ..."

Comment: You are right. I never quite liked the OpenCV documentation. Who puts in a sentence saying only X is possible, only to write something else in the next paragraph?
A side my ranting, this would still not solve my answer. I need the files to be decodable with the algorithm above.

Comment: can you give a simple example of a sample float value and the expected result of your encoding? In your first version you overwrite the 8UC1 m1 m2 and m3 by float matrices.

Comment: can your original float values contain values > 255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, but it is not very pretty.

I just perform the conversion on each value, with a few bit operations and bit-shifting like so:

```
void saveLUT(Mat in, char const* filename){
    int i,j;

    Mat c1(imageSize, CV_8UC1);
    Mat c2(imageSize, CV_8UC1);
    Mat c3(imageSize, CV_8UC1);

    for(i = 0; i < in.cols; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < in.rows; j++){
            float orig = in.at<float>(j,i);

            uint32_t orig_int = orig*(256.0*256.0*256.0-1);
            c1.at<uint8_t>(j,i) = (uint8_t)((orig_int&0xFF0000) >> 16);
            c2.at<uint8_t>(j,i) = (uint8_t)((orig_int&0x00FF00) >> 8);
            c3.at<uint8_t>(j,i) = (uint8_t)((orig_int&0x0000FF));
        }
    }

    std::vector<Mat> channels;
    channels.push_back(c1);
    channels.push_back(c2);
    channels.push_back(c3);
    Mat out;
    merge(channels, out);
    imwrite(filename, out);

    Mat encoded(imageSize, CV_8UC4);

}
```

It's not pretty to look at and I have to assume there are faster methods to do this, but I did not find any and it runs fast enough for my purpose.

Comment: Should be much faster if you change the loop order to iterate over rows in the outer loop.

Comment: Interesting. Care to explain why?

Comment: because of better caching and/or swapping behaviour. if colums are processed first, the program has to jump in memory a lot while processing full rows first will process exactly in memory order of the image.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is essentially a conversion from type `CV_32FC1` to type `CV_8UC4` that you can then save as a PNG file.

This can be achieved in one line in C++ using the data pointers:

```
cv::Mat floatImage; // Your CV_32FC1 Mat
cv::Mat pngImage(floatImage.rows, floatImage.cols, CV_8UC4, (cv::Vec4b*)floatImage.data);
```

What you obtain is a 4-channel 8-bit precision image where each pixel contains one of the floating-point values in your original image separated in 4 blocks of 8 bits.

The inverse transformation is also possible:

```
cv::Mat pngImage;
cv::Mat floatImage(pngImage.rows, pngImage.cols, CV_32FC1, (float*)pngImage.data);
```

Comment: Hm I do not want to just take the highest bits of the float values and store them (I admit I posed my question wrong). I need the values to be reconstructable with the above algorithm. I actually would want the highest bits if the float was multiplied by 256^4. But then the value would need to be stored in a 32bit integer, and there are no 32bit mats in OpenCV. Therefore I cannot use this solution.

Comment: Also, imwrite would not accept a 4-channel image, so you would have to throw away one of the channels before saving. But then this would be a pretty neat way to store a CV_32FC1 Mat in only a few lines, just not right for my purpose.

Comment: @BT9  Where did you see that opencv didn't have 32 bit mats? Or that you couldn't save 4 channels images... Why do you think the type is called CV_**32**FC1?

Comment: I meant 32bit integer mats. They need to be decodable with the algorithm I posted, so floatmats are not suitable.

Also, not all of the bits in a float value are for the value only, so 0.99999*(256^4) would be too large for a 32 bit float.

Comment: And from 
[link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite):
The function imwrite saves the image to the specified file. The image format is chosen based on the filename extension (see imread() for the list of extensions). Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

So CV_32FC1 is not storable using imwrite without loosing precision.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite) more carefully, you will see this: "It is possible to store PNG images with an alpha channel using this function. To do this, create 8-bit (or 16-bit) 4-channel image BGRA, where the alpha channel goes last. Fully transparent pixels should have alpha set to 0, fully opaque pixels should have alpha set to 255/65535. "  @BT9

Comment: @BT9   Also there are 32-bit integer mats with the type `CV_32S`.

Comment: Yes, but it is signed. Not suitable for my purpose. And I commented on the openCV doc below, not the best out there.